# OpenSearch Description on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, opensearch

I tried to find a way to make an OpenSearch Description available in ie 11. I did find this page, but it had insufficient description.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn832639(v=vs.85).aspx

Questions that arise from that are:

1. What is the namespace for the namespace "ie" as used in ie:NTLogo, ie:NTSearchResult, ie:NTSearchSuggestion
2. The pages says that the osd-xml "need to upload it to IEGallery (or another website)". Where/how can it be uploaded onto other websites.
3. ie:NTLogo it appears to me that the placeholders {language}, {scalefactor}, {contrast}

Comment: The article you linked to is a summary of changes, rather than a full description.  MSDN has a lot more information available about the OpenSearch, though you might have to dig for it.  Here's one place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc891507(v=vs.85).aspx#dev_mainsection.  Yes, these are long.  IE added support some time back and those docs were rarely updated, save for quick fixes.  The info's still good, though and provides some background.  Use the "related information" sections at the bottom of the page for links.  (Also, your question #3 seems incomplete.)

Comment: @Lance Leonard: Thank you. This answers 1/2 for me. 3 is less important to me. If you like, provide this as answer. I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SO's OSD as a template.
[OSD for stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml)

the xmlns attribute values points to a public document that contains the allowed tag names for an xml document of type OSD.

see [opensearch.org](http://opensearch.org)

Comment: It seems to me that those ie-specific extensions are not part of the opensearch standard. That is way, they come with their own namespace 'ie'. I would like to comply with what ie11 expects.